# Problem in struct when creating structure c

Tags: c, struct, enums, structure, typedef

why am I getting error `Genre genre;` part. It says `‘Genre’ does not name a type`
Can somebody explain?

```
// The structure of the Song
typedef struct song
{
    int id_playlist;
    char *artist;
    Genre genre;
    double duration;
    char *name;
    struct song *next;
} Song;


// Enumeration for song genre
typedef enum 
{
    ROCK = 0,
    RAP,
    POP,
    METAL
} Genre;


Song *New_song(char *name, char *artist, double duration, Genre genre);
void Print_song(Song *song);
```

Comment: Hint: Declare it *before* you use it. Compilers can only work with what they've seen up to that point. They don't look into the future.

Comment: @tadman thank you, I forgot about that

Comment: Treat it like telling the compiler a story. You can't involve characters you haven't introduced yet, or it's going to ask "Wait, who's this new person?"

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler reads the `Genre genre;` line in the structure definition, it hasn't interpreted yet the definition of `Genre` below. If you swap both, this should work fine:

```
// Enumeration for song genre
typedef enum 
{
    ROCK = 0,
    RAP,
    POP,
    METAL
} Genre;

// The structure of the Song
typedef struct song
{
    int id_playlist;
    char *artist;
    Genre genre;
    double duration;
    char *name;
    struct song *next;
} Song;
```

In other words, you have to define something before you can use it.